# Probability of series

Tags: probability-theory

The urn has a white ball and a black ball. There is an experience consisting in pulling out one of the balls at random and then returning to the urn and so n (party) times. Example series (based on the repetition of one color) wbbwww-a series of 1 white, a series of two black, a series of three white.

1)What is the probability that for n=14 tests there will be no odd series of any color?

2)What is the probability that for n=8 tests there will be no odd series of any color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having no odd series means that balls 1 and 2 are the same color, then balls 3 and 4 are the same color and so on. We don't care if 2,3 or 4,5 etc. are the same. For n = 8, this gives us 4 pairs, and for n = 14 this gives us 7 pairs. Each pair has the same color with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ :

Pr(2 whites) + Pr(2 blacks) = $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$

So this leaves us with:

1) $(\frac{1}{2})^7 = \frac{1}{128}$

2) $(\frac{1}{2})^4 = \frac{1}{16}$